# Is OCamlexample app on iPad usable?

Tags: ipad, ios, ocaml

An Ocaml interpreter app was put up on iTunes last November.  I've done some Haskell programming, and briefly looked into Ocaml at one time, but never really became acquainted with it.  I have a new iPad, and am curious whether the Ocamlexample app available on iPad can actually be used for anything other than working through tutorial exercises.

I.e., does anyone know if it has the capability to save scripts (in its sandbox, of course), and any ability to export results (other than cut and paste)?

I can't find any references on Google much more current than last November, so it would appear that no one is actually doing anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple dropped many of their restrictions on iOS software development on September 9, 2010.  Here is the press release announcing the changes:

[Changes to development agreement Sept 9, 2010.](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html)

The only restriction now is that you can't *download* code.  I.e., you can't have an embedded language implementation that is its own app platform.

This does limit the usefulness of an interpreter, but there is no rule against interpreters per se or against saving and reloading scripts in a particular iPad.

You can also compile OCaml to run on iOS.  That's what I'm spending my time on right now, and I'm selling an OCaml iOS app in the iTunes Store.  Visit my profile for a link.

(Hmm--I just noticed this was a pretty old question.  Sorry for any extra noise.)

Answer (score 1):

You can download scripts, but only if the mac/pc is tethered to the ipad and you use the dropbox function of ios. in theory this could be a program which opens a socket for your own protocol, however I have not tried this. It would have to be a single threaded protocol because Lwt is not implemented

Answer (score -1):

From the way it's pitched, and knowing the App Store's rules, I don't think it's actually for making OCaml scripts. It just lets you do a limited set of calculations and drawing operations. Apple would reject it if they actually thought it was a programming language interpreter.

Comment: Not completely obvious to me.  There have apparently been recent changes in the rules and now there are a number of apps that allow interpreted languages.  I understand that the scripts cannot be downloaded -- although if the interpreter is sandbox safe, this seems lame, if true.  An issue for me would be can I save scripts in the sandbox.   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891642/interpreter-for-the-iphone)